# Makefile not creating executable

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

So I have been searching stack overflow and the rest of the internet, and while I have found similar questions to mine, I have not found one in which the answer works for my issue. I am just learning how to create makefiles and would appreciate any help. I first created a makefile with variable "objects", when I typed make it would compile the .c files creating .o files, however, no executable was made. 
this was what my makefile looked like:

```
objects = user_interface.o interacts.o linked_list_funcs.o

proj4ex: $(objects)
<tab> cc -o proj4ex $(objects)
user_interface.o: user_interface.c header.h
<tab> cc -c user_interface.c
interacts.o: interacts.c header.h
<tab> cc -c interacts.c
linked_list_funcs.o: linked_list_funcs.c header.h
<tab> cc -c linked_list_funcs.c
clean:
<tab> rm proj4ex $(objects)
```

I then tried to alter my makefile to be the exact same thing, but with the file names instead of the variable "objects". When using make with this new form of my makefile, it seems to compile but I get errors about my code. I am not sure if I am misunderstanding the error, but I believe it would mean my variable "debugMode" was declared several times which it was not. This is what I get when using the makefile with file names listed

[image]

I am wondering if my original makefile was not correctly reading the other files? Just very confused here and would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps your `debugMode` variable is defined in header.h? Then this will give you _three_ definitions, as indicated by the error messages.

Comment: Yes it is defined in header.h, that makes a lot of sense thank you. I am a bit confused though, I need the variable for two of my files (used several times in linked_list_funcs and once in user_interface), if two files need the variable, where should I put the declaration instead so that they can both access it?

Answer (score 0):

Like Joseph said, the compiler is telling you you defined the 'debugMode' identifier multiple times. You can tell because it's referencing the .bss section, which has to do with the binary, not make. In addition, the linker `ld` is clearly what's failing at that step, which makes sense because that *is* a linker error.

That being said, I would make the following recommendations for your makefile. Internally, Make already knows how to compile c files, and it looks like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $^
```

That recipe will build all the necessary object files from c files, but again, Make already knows that. If you're going to write a recipe out all the way, it should be because you're adding extra things necessary for the project. You want to specify the compiler as $(CC) so that when your users compile the project they can specify the compiler of their choice like this: `make CC=icc` or whatever.

To emphasize the main point though, the problem is in your code, not the makefile.

Comment: Thank you for the detail, the issue is definitely because of the debugMode variable being declared in the header.h file. I am a bit confused as to where this should be declared instead though as two of my files need the variable. Are you suggesting that I should put that recipe in my makefile, or saying that it already exists in the makefile?

Comment: @vince: The simplest solution is to put `extern int debugMode;` in the header, and `int debugMode;` in the `main` file.